# Create a two step registration form using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My application allows two kinds of users: resellers and buyers. Each one of them have different custom fields, then I need to add a first step in the registration where the user can select the kind of user he is, the email address and the password. After clicking on Register it will be redirected to a page to complete its profile.

Device registration view uses this code:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

But I need to add the registration form to my Application layout as it will be accessible from the navbar. Do I have to copy the Devise view code as it is? I mean, the view uses variables defined on Devise's controller. Will it work from my layout/other controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the form should be visible in the nav bar itself (rather than the nav bar just containing a link to the registration page), then yes, it will work wherever you put it as the `:url` is specified in the `simple_form_for` statement.

That said, I would recommend not to copy this code to your `application.html.erb` layout: you should put it in a partial (e.g. `_sign_up.html.erb`) and only render it from the application layout:

```
<%= render 'sign_up' unless user_signed_in? %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. About the registration form being visible to signed in users, how can I solve this without adding logic to the view?

Comment: I have updated my answer. On second thought, given the complexity of the logic I don't really think that's a problem :)

Comment: One more question: considering that Devise has its own controller/action to create the user and I need this second step to finish creating the user's profile, should I create a new controller so I have one action for each step, or should I change Devise's controller to redirect to the Profile controller after signing up?

Comment: You should extend Devise's controller. Most of Devise's actions support passing a block to the parent class' method. Have a look at [this article](http://www.enlightenedpixel.com/the-open-closed-principle-at-work-within-devise/) for more details.